# ActiveRecord has_one having conditions does not set condition attributes on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3:

I have Review, User and ReviewAccess classes

```
class ReviewAccess < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
  attr_accessible :role_id
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :review_accesses_owner, :class_name => 'ReviewAccess',
    :conditions => "review_accesses.role_id = 1"
  has_one :owner, :class_name => 'User', :through => :review_accesses_owner,
   :source => :user
end
```

Basically Review is many-to-many with User and the join table is ReviewAccess where it additionally holds the relation role (1 for owner) in role_id column.
I can read the the review owner by:

```
Review.owner  # works
# sql: SELECT "review_accesses".* FROM "review_accesses" WHERE "review_accesses"."review_id" = 7 AND (review_accesses.role_id = 1) LIMIT 1
```

However, setting the owner does not work because it doesn't set role_id to 1 (as stated in the conditions clause of the association)

```
Review.owner = current_user  # does not set role_id
# sql: INSERT INTO "review_accesses" ("created_at", "review_id", "role_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 27 Oct 2013 08:02:54 UTC +00:00], ["review_id", 7], ["role_id", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 27 Oct 2013 08:02:54 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
```

I know I can override owner= but I have many of these (for each role) and I want to use the association DSL instead.

How to update associations having conditions to set the conditions on creation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit afraid that using DSL it's not a good choice.

1. Prefer overriding accesorrs than putting code into callbacks if you need add some custom behavior.
2. To some generic, repetitive methods use metaprogramming stuff. If you'll have many roles you'll have DRY in your association definitions still, so problem is the same but in different place.

To sum up, override writer by using metaprogramming for it. Anywhere you have an array of roles, right?

Comment: Yes I have a roles table holding id and name. The table is kinda static having only 3 roles (owner, collaborator and viewer). May be it would be overkill to use metaprogramming here. Is there any way to make use of the association << and association.build methods without overriding the setters?

Comment: Using sophisticated tricks with AR is worse. In general Active Record has too broad API, ant it leads to creating problems where these problems don't exist because of willing using dedicated in this library method. Just override writer, it doesn't matter by which method.